# Accidentally turned a file into a folder

Tags: bash, files, python, directory, mv

So I was working on a python script that allows me to use a 7 segment display via scripting. I added functionality to read a byte from a string, presets for certain numbers, etc. It took me a solid 4 hours to make. I decided to move this file  using:

`mv display/display.py display`

I forgot to add the file extension at the end. I may have forgot a certain part of the command, however this is roughly what I put in. When I went to check the file, it wasn't there, all I could find was `/display`. I used nano to check it, to find out that my entire morning's work was reduced to: `/display is a directory!`. I am 99% sure that this is what used to be my `display.py` file. Is there any way to recover my data, or do I have to start over?

Comment: The command you give should do nothing, with a warning if you’re using a typical Linux distribution (“mv: 'display/display.py' and 'display/display.py' are the same file”). Are you sure your file isn’t still there in `display/display.py`?

Comment: If you move a file to a name of an existing directory, the file will be moved into that directory.

Comment: `mv xy ...` without noting the full path/name of xy should do nothing (beside error reporting). There must be some other reason for this...

Comment: You should always be able to find the exact command you typed in the shell history, so you can figure what it did.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, I didn't remember my command correctly. It actually got renamed to a different name entirely. I checked a file of the same name I gave it, and sure enough, it has my code in it.